# Using Parse get All User data

Tags: android

I use parse AnyPhone for Login using mobile number and after successfully login (OTP verification),  i want to get all parse user from User table for that i used bellow query but i only get Login user Data not all. Thanks in Advance.

```
ArrayList<String> Email = new ArrayList<String>();
                    Email.add("test2@gmail.com");
                    Email.add("test@g.com");
                    Email.add("test@gmail.com");
    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
                        query.whereContainedIn("email", Email);
                        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
                                if(e==null){
                                    Log.i("Size",""+objects.size());
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved My Problem by setting ACL in javascript File.Now i am getting all the Users.

```
var acl = new Parse.ACL();
            // public can read
            acl.setPublicReadAccess( true );
            // public cannot write
            acl.setPublicWriteAccess( false );
            // user can read data
            acl.setReadAccess( user.id, true );
            // user can write data
            acl.setWriteAccess( user.id, false );
            user.setACL(acl);   
            user.save();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void getAllParseUser() {

        ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.whereNotEqualTo(ParseTableConstants.OBJECT_ID, user.getObjectId());
        progressBar.showProgress();
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    // The query was successful.
                    insertData(objects);
                } else {
                    // Something went wrong.
                    progressBar.hideProgress();

                }
            }
        });
    }
This code will give you all parse user
```